# Unable to get field from form

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc

So I am completely new to Spring Boot MVC and Thymeleaf. This is what I am trying to make. A form which the user fills out and presses submit, upon submission, Spring creates an object of type `Spitter` and populates its fields with what the user typed in into the form. And after creating it, it should view the results page in which it displays what the user typed in... very easy in theory.

This is what I have at the moment:

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/spittles")
public class SpittleController {

Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

@RequestMapping(value = "/viewMock", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String spittles(Model model) {
    Spitter spitterObj;
    model.addAttribute("spittle",
            spitterObj = new Spitter(22222, "MOCK", "MOCK"));
    SpitterContainer.containterContaingSpittles.add(spitterObj);
    return "spittles";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String register(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("spitter", new Spitter());


    return "form";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerSubmit(@ModelAttribute Spitter spitter, Model model) {
    String info = String.format("Spitter Submission: id = %s, firstname = %s, lastname = %s",
            spitter.getID(), spitter.getUsername(), spitter.getPassword());
    log.info(info);
    model.addAttribute("spitter", spitter);
    SpitterContainer.containterContaingSpittles.add(new Spitter(44444, spitter.getUsername(), spitter.getPassword()));
    return "result";
}
}
```

Spitter Class:

```
public class Spitter {

private int ID;
private String username;
private String password;


public Spitter(){};

public Spitter(int ID, String us, String pwd){
    setID(ID);
    setPassword(pwd);
    setUsername(us);
}

public String getID() {
    return Integer.toString(ID) ;
}

public void setID(int ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public List<String> getSpittles() {
    return spittles;
}

public void setSpittles(List<String> spittles) {
    this.spittles = spittles;
}

private List<String> spittles;
```

}

Form View:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>REGISTRATION FORM</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:object="${spitter}" method="post">
        <p>username: <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" /></p>
        <p>password: <input type="text" th:field="*{password}"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>

</body>
```

Results View:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Result</h1>
<p th:text="'id: ' + ${spitter.getID}" />
<p th:text="'First Name: ' + ${spitter.getUsername}" />
<p th:text="'Password Name: ' + ${spitter.getPassword}" />
<a href="/form">Submit another Customer Form</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I know this is badly written code but I want to get this simple thing working. The log output the write details (ignoring the ID number but I know why) but I get the following error:
`org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'getID' cannot be found on object of type 'hello.data.Spitter' - maybe not public?`

Any ideas?

Comment: How about `spitter.ID` or `spitter.iD` instead of `spitter.getID`?

Answer (score 0):

Change your result view:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Result</h1>
<p th:text="'id: ' + ${spitter.ID}" />
<p th:text="'First Name: ' + ${spitter.username}" />
<p th:text="'Password Name: ' + ${spitter.password}" />
<a href="/form">Submit another Customer Form</a>
</body>
</html>
```

You should use fields name, not getter methods.